# Iterating through array elements when arrays are stored in a list in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I have a small dilemma. I am writing a small application and am at the end stage of it, and cant decide the best way to go about this.

The program takes a string from the user in a textbox control.

From there it iterates over each character in the string: for each character it has, there is a matching array of substitute characters. Those arrays get added to a `list<string[]>`

From there though, I would like to iterate once more to generate another list which would create substitute words for the users input, gathering all possible combinations.

For example, DAN would become Dan, DaN, DAn, D@n, and so on, using whatever characters were available.

The program supports only 0-9 and a-z (either case) at this point.
*I start inside the class declaring/defining a few arrays and lists:*

```
    public List<String> passwordList = new List<String>();
    public List<string[]> arrayList = new List<string[]>();
    public int arrayListLength;


    public string[] zeroArray = {"0", "o", "O"}; //line for number 0
    public string[] oneArray = {"1", "!", "I", "i", "|"}; //line for number 1
    public string[] twoArray = {"2"}; //line for number 2
    public string[] threeArray = {"3"}; //line for number 3
    public string[] fourArray = {"4", "a", "A"}; //line for number 4
    public string[] fiveArray = {"5", "s", "S", "$"}; //line for number 5
    public string[] sixArray = {"6"}; //line for number 6
    public string[] sevenArray = {"7"}; //line for number 7
    public string[] eightArray = {"8"}; //line for number 8
    public string[] nineArray = {"9"}; //line for number 9

    public string[] aArray = {"a", "A", "4", "@"}; //line for letter a
    public string[] bArray = {"b", "B", "8"}; //line for letter b
    public string[] cArray = {"c", "C", "("};//line for letter c
    public string[] dArray = {"d", "D"}; //line for letter d
    public string[] eArray = {"e", "E"}; //line for letter e
    public string[] fArray = {"f", "F"}; //line for letter f
    public string[] gArray = {"g", "G"}; //line for letter g
    public string[] hArray = {"h", "H"}; //line for letter h
    public string[] iArray = {"i", "I", "!", "|"}; //line for letter i
    public string[] jArray = {"j", "J"}; //line for letter j
    public string[] kArray = {"k", "K"}; //line for letter k
    public string[] lArray = {"l", "L"}; //line for letter l
    public string[] mArray = {"m", "M"}; //line for letter m
    public string[] nArray ={"n", "N"}; //line for letter n
    public string[] oArray = {"o", "O", "0"}; //line for letter o
    public string[] pArray = {"p", "P"}; //line for letter p
    public string[] qArray = {"q", "Q"}; //line for letter q
    public string[] rArray = {"r", "R"}; //line for letter r
    public string[] sArray = {"s", "S", "5", "$"}; //line for letter s
    public string[] tArray = {"t", "T", "+"}; //line for letter t
    public string[] uArray = {"u", "U"}; //line for letter u
    public string[] vArray = {"v", "V"}; //line for letter v
    public string[] wArray = {"w", "W"}; //line for letter w
    public string[] xArray = {"x", "X"}; //line for letter x
    public string[] yArray = {"y", "Y"}; //line for letter y
    public string[] zArray = {"z", "Z"}; //line for letter z
```

Later, when iterating, the loop looks something like this:

```
 String generateFrom = txtGenerateFrom.Text;

        foreach (char c in generateFrom)
            if (c.ToString() == "0")
                arrayList.Add(zeroArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "1")
                arrayList.Add(oneArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "2")
                arrayList.Add(twoArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "3")
                arrayList.Add(threeArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "4")
                arrayList.Add(fourArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "5")
                arrayList.Add(fiveArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "6")
                arrayList.Add(sixArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "7")
                arrayList.Add(sevenArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "8")
                arrayList.Add(eightArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "9")
                arrayList.Add(nineArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "a" || c.ToString() == "A")
                arrayList.Add(aArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "b" || c.ToString() == "B")
                arrayList.Add(bArray);
            else if (c.ToString() == "c" || c.ToString() == "C")
                arrayList.Add(cArray);
```

This gets me a list (`public List<string[]> arrayList = new List<string[]>();//declared at beginning` ) which contains the relevant arrays, and the arrays are in order by where they belong relevant to the user input.

**What then is the best way to loop over this list to make my strings and add them to a list of words which can substitute?**

Comment: Firstly, I would *strongly* advise you do use braces even when you don't strictly need to. I would definitely put braces around the body of your `foreach` loop for readability. Next, it's not clear to me where the digits come from - it would really help if you'd give a full example, as the partial examples you've given so far don't really describe the problem clearly IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, give me a moment, I will make some edits

Comment: I hope those edits make it a little more sensical. If it hits the character t or T character first, it would add the tArray array to the arrayList list, so that later on I know that the 't' substitute characters belong first in the new words.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Dictionary<char, string[]>` or `Dictionary<string, string[]>` then... I wouldn't have all those separate variables.

Comment: Does accessing elements in the array work the same way in dictionaries?

Comment: Further still, Its the part with the generating the replacement words which has me confused

Comment: Well I'd learn about dictionaries in general first - note that you'd use the dictionary to *get at* the array... you'd then still have an array reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class:

```
public static class PasswordGenerator
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<char, char[]> Substitutions = new Dictionary<char, char[]> {
        {'0', new[] {'0', 'o', 'O'}},
        {'1', new[] {'1', '!', 'I', 'i', '|'}},
        {'2', new[] {'2'}},
        {'3', new[] {'3'}},
        {'4', new[] {'4', 'a', 'A'}},
        {'5', new[] {'5', 's', 'S', '$'}},
        {'6', new[] {'6'}},
        {'7', new[] {'7'}},
        {'8', new[] {'8'}},
        {'9', new[] {'9'}},
        {'a', new[] {'a', 'A', '4', '@'}},
        {'b', new[] {'b', 'B', '8'}},
        {'c', new[] {'c', 'C', '('}},
        {'d', new[] {'d', 'D'}},
        {'e', new[] {'e', 'E'}},
        {'f', new[] {'f', 'F'}},
        {'g', new[] {'g', 'G'}},
        {'h', new[] {'h', 'H'}},
        {'i', new[] {'i', 'I', '!', '|'}},
        {'j', new[] {'j', 'J'}},
        {'k', new[] {'k', 'K'}},
        {'l', new[] {'l', 'L'}},
        {'m', new[] {'m', 'M'}},
        {'n', new[] {'n', 'N'}},
        {'o', new[] {'o', 'O', '0'}},
        {'p', new[] {'p', 'P'}},
        {'q', new[] {'q', 'Q'}},
        {'r', new[] {'r', 'R'}},
        {'s', new[] {'s', 'S', '5', '$'}},
        {'t', new[] {'t', 'T', '+'}},
        {'u', new[] {'u', 'U'}},
        {'v', new[] {'v', 'V'}},
        {'w', new[] {'w', 'W'}},
        {'x', new[] {'x', 'X'}},
        {'y', new[] {'y', 'Y'}},
        {'z', new[] {'z', 'Z'}}
    };

    public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateFor(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        return GenerateFor(value, value.ToCharArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GenerateFor(string src, char[] value, int index = 0)
    {
        if (index < value.Length)
        {
            char[] chars;
            while (!Substitutions.TryGetValue(char.ToLowerInvariant(src[index]), out chars))
                if (++index == src.Length)
                {
                    yield return new string(value);
                    yield break;
                }

            foreach (var c in chars)
            {
                value[index] = c;
                foreach (var nextValue in GenerateFor(src, value, index + 1))
                    yield return nextValue;
            }
        }
        else
            yield return new string(value);
    }
}
```

- This class generates all possible variations of input string using lookup dictionary;
- All unspecified characters processed as characters with single substitution;
- For any input string generator returns at least one string (copy of input string) and more strings if any substitutions exists;

You can use it like this:

```
foreach (var password in PasswordGenerator.GenerateFor("DAN"))
    Console.WriteLine(password);
```

And this code output:

```
dan
daN
dAn
dAN
d4n
d4N
d@n
d@N
Dan
DaN
DAn
DAN
D4n
D4N
D@n
D@N
```

Comment: wow. absolutely what i was looking for. I made a small change, in that rather than print the current version to the screen, it adds it to a list of strings, then will later dump that to a file

Comment: "absolutely what i was looking for" - this means you can mark this answer as the best, ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. First replace the array declartions with a `Dictionary`:

```
public static Dictionary<char, char[]> replacementLookup = new Dictionary<char, char[]>()
        {
                { '0', new char[] { 'o', 'O' } }, 
                { '1', new char[] { '!', 'I', 'i', '|' } }, 
                { '4', new char[] { 'a', 'A' } }
                // Rest of data...
        };
```

Then you can iterate over your input (using `Distinct` to avoid duplicates) and use LINQ `Select` to get the list of strings for each replacement character:

```
var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var c in input.Distinct().Where(x => replacementLookup.ContainsKey(x)))
{
    result.AddRange(replacementLookup[c].Select(replacement => input.Replace(c, replacement)));
}
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at here. I'll play with this for awhile